# Qt Show Half of Widget

Tags: c++, qt, animation

I have a QGroupBox widget that I am animating off the screen. The problem is that I only want to show certain parts of the group box. For example if the widget is 200 pixels in width how do I only show the first 100 pixels with out changing the size of the widget and making the layout go funny?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean you want to set a [minimum size](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop)? Have you tried anything yet or searched through the documentation?

Comment: @user174084: If you've come up with an solution that satisfies your original question it's totally acceptable to submit and accept that as an answer. That way the question remains on SO for posterity, but does not remain unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

I have come up with a solution. By placing the widget inside of another group box and animating it to move out side the bounds of the group box produces the desired result.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão As far as I know, he has to wait about 1 or 2 days to do so.